# What is the source of the above mantra?

Tags: mantras

What is the source of the above mantra?

Krishna kesava Krishna kesava Krishna kesava pahi mam

Rama raghava Rama raghava Rama raghava raksha mam

Answer (score 2):

Chaitanya Charitamrita

https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/7/96/

> kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! he
> kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! he
> kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! rakṣa mām
> kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! kṛṣṇa! pāhi mām
> rāma! rāghava! rāma! rāghava! rāma! rāghava! rakṣa mām
> kṛṣṇa! keśava! kṛṣṇa! keśava! kṛṣṇa! keśava! pāhi mām